# 14/45 day notice

Tags: credit-card

On 1 March I receive the 45-day notification stating that higher interest rate will be charged on any new transactions made after 14 days from the date of the notice. 
On 10 March I made a $100 purchase.
My question is till which date the regular APR will be charged on $100 purchase amount?

Comment: Of course, this won't matter if you pay your card off every month... :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your purchase was made before the 14 day deadline, you'll receive the regular APR until the 45 days have elapsed. Call you credit card company. They can provide the exact terms.

Comment: that is in the case that I choose to opt out. right?

Comment: I believe so, but just make a quick call to your credit card company. They should be able easily answer these types of questions!

Comment: @tanumalik: (Assuming your notice is like ones I have received) If you opt out, your rate will not increase.... but you will no longer be able to make any new charges.  You'll just pay it down and then not have a card since rejecting the increase closes the account.